# Probable version skew in pre-compiled xxx

Tags: raku

I'm installing a package onto a virtual machine(ubuntu18.04).
Here are the instructions I used:

```
apt-get install perl6 && \
 git clone https://github.com/ugexe/zef.git && cd zef && perl6 -I. bin/zef install . && \
 /usr/lib/perl6/site/bin/zef install Shell::Command && \
 PYTHON_CONFIG=/usr/bin/python3-config \
 /usr/lib/perl6/site/bin/zef -v install https://github.com/eatingtomatoes/Inline-Python3.git --/test --debug
```

Following is the output:

```
....
===> Building [OK] for Inline::Python3:ver<0.1>
===> Installing: LibraryMake:ver<1.0.0>:auth<github:retupmoca>
===> Install [OK] for LibraryMake:ver<1.0.0>:auth<github:retupmoca>
===> Installing: Inline::Python3:ver<0.1>
===> Install [FAIL] for Inline::Python3:ver<0.1>: ===SORRY!===
Probable version skew in pre-compiled
 'site#sources/95D204DDA68A3E05E891AA531EBED9270C46B3F7 
(Inline::Python3::InstanceConverter)' (cause: no object at index 499)

===SORRY!===
Probable version skew in pre-compiled 
'site#sources/95D204DDA68A3E05E891AA531EBED9270C46B3F7 
(Inline::Python3::InstanceConverter)' (cause: no object at index 499)
```

When I executed `perl6 -e "use Inline::Python3; say 'hi'"` in shell, it reported:

```
===SORRY!===
Probable version skew in pre-compiled 
'site#sources/95D204DDA68A3E05E891AA531EBED9270C46B3F7 
(Inline::Python3::InstanceConverter)' (cause: no object at index 499)
```

The Inline::Python3 package is a perl6 package developped by myself. It runs well on my pc.

`perl6 --version` said:

```
This is Rakudo version 2018.03 built on MoarVM version 2018.03
implementing Perl 6.c.
```

I don't know what the 'version skew' is. How can I fix the error?

Comment: Where did you get the compiled binaries from? There are a couple of sources you can use (with more up-to-date versions), https://rakudo.org/files and Claudio's https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg. Inline::Python3 was just updated, too: https://github.com/eatingtomatoes/Inline-Python3 Maybe you can try and download from source instead.

Answer (score 6):

Following @jjmerelo's advice, using the latest compiler provided by [rakudo-pkg](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg) solved the problem.